# Elaboration of a step in the proof of Proposition 9 on Page80 Royden "fourth edition".

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral

The proposition and a part of its proof are given below:

> [image]

My questions are:

In the forward direction: 1- How is the countable additivity of Lebesgue measure is used Should not the given set be described as a countable union of disjoint subsets?

2- How this proves that $f$ equals 0 **a.e.**?

Could anyone help me in answering these questions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (1) is used the subaddittivity of the Lebesgue measure and the fact that $$\{f>0\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{f \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$$

For (2) $m(\{f>0\}) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m(\{f \geq \frac{1}{n}\})=0$

Since $f$ is non-negative anf $m(\{f>0\})=0$ then $f=0$ a.e

Comment: but the sets in the union you mentioned are not disjoint

Comment: how it is 0 a.e. , I can see that it is always 0.

Comment: @Smart for (1), you can use countable subadditivity, namely that $\mu(\cup A_n) \le \sum \mu(A_n)$. While countable *additivity* requires being disjoint, countable *subadditivity* holds for any sequence of sets. We thus have $\mu(\{f > 0\})  = \mu(\cup \{f \ge 1/n\}) \le \sum \mu(\{f \ge 1/n\}) = 0$ as desired

Comment: @Smart for (2), since $f$ is non-negative either $f = 0$ or $f > 0$. Since $f > 0$ almost nowhere, $f = 0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Why $f > 0$ almost nowhere ? why not exactly nowhere? @BrevanEllefsen

Comment: @Smart $\mu(A_n) = 0$ is far from being the same as $A_n = \varnothing$. For example, take the rationals.

Comment: got it. thank you very much for your patience in answering my questions :) @BrevanEllefsen