# Elaboration of a step in the proof of Proposition 9 on Page80 Royden "fourth edition"(2).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral

The proposition and its proof are given below:

> [image]

**My question is:** 
In the proof of the backward direction,  why $h$ has finite support? does this because our assumption was that **$f = 0$ a.e.** on $E$ so that the lower Lebesgue integral of $h$ (a bounded measurable function) over a set of finite measure can be defined and because by definition a function that vanishes outside a set of finite measure has a finite support?

Comment: This is a weird proof for the backwards direction. Just note that if $f = 0$ a.e. then any simple function $s \le f$ will be zero a.e. so $\int_E s$ will be zero for all $s \le f$ so $\int_E f = \sup_{s \le f} \int_E s = 0$. Obviously we can choose such an $h$ in all cases, but it is unclear to me why Royden bothers to do so.

Comment: Could you please look at my comments for the answer to this question if you have time to answer them https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3400803/elaboration-of-a-step-in-the-proof-of-proposition-9-on-page80-royden-fourth-edi ? @BrevanEllefsen

Comment: but is the reason for finite support of $h,$ the one I mentioned in the question correct? @BrevanEllefsen

Comment: your reasoning is not quite correct. For example, consider Dirichlet's function, being $1$ on the rationals and $0$ on the irrationals. This function does not have finite support; if you define $\operatorname{Supp}(f) = \{x \mid f(x) \neq 0\}$ then the support is the rationals, which are not finite (and even worse, if you define $\operatorname{Supp}(f) = \overline{\{x \mid f(x) \neq 0\}}$ then the support is the whole real line). Nevertheless, $h$ exists here because we can just choose a finite subset of the points where $f$ is nonzero and only on this set let $h$ be nonzero.

Comment: Are you criticizing my definition of finite support? this definition is in Royden on pg.79 @BrevanEllefsen

Comment: I do not understand the statement between parentheses in your last comment @BrevanEllefsen

Comment: there are multiple definitions of the support of a function depending on the context you are in; sometimes it's just the points where your functions is nonzero, and sometimes it is the closure of that set (if your measure space has a topology on it). I point out that your reasoning is not quite correct regardless of definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's how the authors *define* the integral of nonnegative measurable functions. See (8) in Definition on page 79 of Royden-Fitzpatrick:

> For $f$ a nonnegative measurable function on $E$, we define the integral of $f$ over $E$ by
>   $$
> \int_Ef=\{\int_Eh\mid h \text{ bounded, measurable, of finite support and } 0\le h\le f \text{ on } E\}
> $$

By this definition, to show that $\int_Ef=0$, it suffices to show that $\int_Eh=0$ for all "such" $h$ in the definition above.

For any given such $h$, it is Lebesgue integrable by Theorem 3 (page 73 on Royden-Fitzpatrick). Thus to show that $\int_E h=0$, one can show that
$$
\sup\{\int_E\varphi \mid \varphi \text{ simple and } \varphi\le h \text{ on } E\}=0.
$$
And since $f$ is nonnegative, it suffices to show that
$$
\sup\{\int_E\varphi \mid \varphi \text{ simple and } 0\le\varphi\le h \text{ on } E\}=0.
$$

Comment: My question was why we are sure that we can find $h$ of finite support?

Comment: I think $h$ is Lebesgue integrable definition requires $\phi \leq h,$ not  $\phi \leq f.$ .... am I correct?

Comment: How can I draw a picture?

Comment: @Smart: can you draw the graph of a nonnegative function?

Comment: yes I can .... linear or nonlinear?

Comment: Drawing a picture is unnecessary. An $h$ with the desired properties always exists: given any nonnegative function $f$ let $h(x):=f(x)$ when $x\in U\cap \{x:f(x)<n\}$ where $U\subset E$ and $U$ has the finite Lebesgue measure and let $h(x):=0$ for $E\setminus U$.

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what was explained to me by Brevan ................. thank you so much also, Jack, for your great help for me :)